# How to reference particular button in a css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

In my code I have a lot of button tags. For the one mentioned below in the code I want to add some styles to it in a css file.

How can I reference this particular button among the other ones? I believe I need to assign that button to something like a variable and then reference that variable in the CSS file. How can I achieve that?

**Code**:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SITE_TOPOGRAPHY')">
  <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Please try to observe the standard case rules for English - it makes this much easier to read. Moreover, it leaves volunteer editors with less to repair. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add a css class:

HTML:

```
class="btn btn-sm btn-icon my-fancy-button"
```

CSS:

```
.my-fancy-button {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: what is is-solid and btn-icon??

Comment: idk, that's from your code... certainly bootstrap classes

Comment: but is-silide is from your answer..can i use btn-sm instead of my-fancy-button?

Comment: Oh, I misread your code, `is-solid` is in a child component indeed. You may use the class name you wish yeah.

Comment: is-solid is a class name,right?how did you know that it is a chils component please

Comment: in your code, you have a `<clr-icon>` inside your button, which has the class `is-solid`